# How can I make my image grid stack in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, grid, stack

I have pictures vertical and horizontal, I wanted to make waterfall/masonry/pinterest grid layout, I found out that it's possible to make a 'stack' grid, but I've tried many different codes and I still didn't manage to make it, because I want to implement it to my existing code (and I am too fresh to do so). Maybe there is easier way to do it? 
Thank you in advance

```
<template >
  <v-container
    fluid
    grid-list-xs
    text-xs-center
    fill-height
    max-height: 100vh;
    class="product"

  >
    <v-layout align-center justify-center row wrap class="container">
      <v-flex xs10 sm6 md4 lg3 class="mr-2 mb-2" v-for="(obj,key) in portfolio" :key="key">
        <v-hover>
          <v-card flat slot-scope="{ hover }" class="mx-auto" color="transparent">
            <v-img  class="image" v-bind:src="obj.img">
              <v-expand-transition>
                <div
                  v-if="hover"
                  class="d-flex transition-fast-in-fast-out grey darken-4 v-card--reveal display-3 white--text"
                  style="height: 100%;"
                >
                  <h4>{{ obj.title }}</h4>
                </div>
              </v-expand-transition>
            </v-img>
          </v-card>
        </v-hover>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a top level v-layout and v-flex.

Try it like this:

```
<template>
  <v-layout justify-center>
    <v-flex xs12>
     <v-card>
        <v-container
          fluid
          grid-list-xs
        >
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex
              xs10 sm6 md4 lg3 class="mr-2 mb-2" v-for="(obj,key) in portfolio" :key="key"
            >
              <v-card>
                <v-img
                  class="image" :src="obj.img"
                >
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div
                      v-if="hover" 
                     class="d-flex transition-fast-in-fast-out grey darken-4 v-card--reveal display-3 white--text"
                     style="height: 100%;"
                    >
                      <h4>{{ obj.title }}</h4>
                    </div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                </v-img>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

Comment: It is a bit closer to the result I want, but.. Maybe JS could help here, to put pictures random so there won't be empty spaces between them.

Comment: What empty spaces are there?

Comment: Ahh, so the images are different heights? You'd have to set a max-height on the v-card wrapping the v-img. I think v-img automatically vertically centers the image.

Comment: But that's the point, I don't want them to be cropped. Perhaps it is possible to make 3 different columns? I can make one, but it's never ending instead of making columns in 3 rows.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're trying to do. Each row will start at the bottom of the previous one which is why the gaps. I'll try and think of a solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at [this](https://github.com/MopTym/vue-waterfall). Seems to do what you want.